Was there a single word or simple phrase that had the same meaning as silhouette before it entered the language
The word silhouette has its origins in Étienne de Silhouette's (France's finance minister under Louis XV) hobby of making cut-paper shadow portraits. Merriam-Webster
Was there a single word or two-word phrase before the second half of the 18th century that had the same meaning as seeing only the dark shape of an object in front of a brighter background?

Silhouette appears to be unique in its specific sense. - “Some common synonyms of silhouette are contour, outline, and profile. While all these words mean "the line that bounds and gives form to something," silhouette suggests a shape especially of a head or figure with all detail blacked out in shadow leaving only the outline clearly defined. (MW)” https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/silhouette#:~:text=Some%20common%20synonyms%20of%20silhouette,only%20the%20outline%20clearly%20defined.

@user66974 The first entry of that link reads, "as in outline-a line that traces the outer limits of an object or surface." While the meaning originally referred to a head or a figure, its meaning has expanded to include objects.

I would guess 'shadow'? BTW, Wikipedia doesn't say that de Silhouette made the portraits himself, just that his name was a by-word for doing things on the cheap.

@KateBunting Merriam-Webster also mentions that, "de Silhouette was France's finance minister under Louis XV and was notorious for both his frugality and his hobby...the phrase à la Silhouette came to mean "on the cheap." I was under the impression a shadow was an image cast on another object, not absence of light reflecting off the original object

I'm not sure what you mean. As I understand it, a silhouette portrait was made by having the subject cast a shadow on a sheet of paper and drawing round it.

It's not clear from your comments and question exactly what is meant. Do you mean silhouette as in the outline of a form, the outline with the contents blacked out, or specifically a shape cut out of paper? And in terms of content, specifically the profile of a face or something else? (It appears you are excluding shadows.)

There are also related foreign-language terms like the Greek melanomorpha (black-figure) and German Scherenschnitte ("scissor cuts"). Neither is exactly the same but there is cross-over (neither seems to have wide currency in English but it's hard to be certain).
